# What is meant with a buffer in python

Tags: python, io, buffer

In the python documentation for struct, the word buffer is used without explanation:

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

> `struct.unpack_from(fmt, buffer[,offset=0])`
>
> Unpack the buffer
>   according to the given format. The
>   result is a tuple even if it contains
>   exactly one item. The buffer must
>   contain at least the amount of data
>   required by the format
>   (len(buffer[offset:]) must be at least
>   calcsize(fmt)).

What is meant here with a buffer. Is a string a buffer, or a file descriptor? What methods must a 'buffer' have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a memory buffer: in Python 2, a string (`str`), in Python 3, a binary string (`bytes`), or alternatively an object constructed with [`buffer`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#buffer).

Comment: The buffer function talks about `an object that supports the buffer call interface`. What is this interface? Does a file descriptor match that, or should I always read into a string first?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/ A file descriptor or file-like object won't work.

Comment: You can use `mmap` to have a memory map to a file without having to read it into a file. http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html

Comment: `mmap` won't work with remote filesystems, though, so be prepared to write a backup routine that does read in the file.